# After deleting Silverlight app's host init-event fires again in IE

Tags: html, silverlight-2.0

When I delete html node with silverlight 2.0 app inside, Init event fires again (only in in IE, but not in FF). How can I cope with this strange behaviour? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe caused by CACHE. try to delete all temporary files for IE

Comment: No, it's not the Cache. I delete html node via javascript.